# How do I enable PowerAutomate to use the Video Analyzer For Media flow?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I tried to upload a Blob video to Video Analyzer For Media with Power Automate by referring to the tutorial below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/azure-video-analyzer/video-analyzer-for-media-docs/logic-apps-connector-tutorial

However, when I created the flow according to the procedure and ran the test, the following error occurred in the third "Get Account Access Token" of the first flow.
[image]

```
Status code: 401
{
  "ErrorType": "INVALID_AUTH_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY",
  "Message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription."
}
```

I considered the following as possible errors.
(1) The input information of the connector is incorrect.
[image]
In the input information of the connector created to create this flow, the AAD secret obtained in "API Access" of Video Analyzer For Media was entered in "API Key".
What should I enter for the "API Key" if this value is incorrect?
If you could understand, please tell me.

(2) The input information of "Account ID" entered in the flow is incorrect.
[image]
For this value, enter the "Account ID" obtained from "Account Settings" on the Azure Video Analyzer For Media Portal (https://www.videoindexer.ai/).
[image]
What should I enter if this value is entered incorrectly?
If you could understand, please tell me.

Also, if the above possibilities are incorrect, we would appreciate it if you could tell us other possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

The API key can be retrieved from this page : https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/profile

The account ID is a GUID. It can be seen in "user accounts" and in account settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for teaching me!
I will check it immediately!

Comment: I was able to connect to Video Analyzer For Media with PowerAutomate!
thank you!